# Multiple behavior subjects: wait until every one has a value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I've got an array of BehaviorSubjects, where i want to fire the Subscription only when everyone of them received a value. I've already tried to use the 'zip' operator. The only problem is that it fires when the value is null or undefined (seems that it only works with normal Subjects). Has anyone faced the same problem and knows how to solve it? 
As the output I want to receive an array with the values.

Comment: Why not filter the null or undefined values *out* of the streams? Alternatively, if you don't have a sensible default value, why use behavior subjects?

Comment: You could use combineLatest to combine the streams. It will only emit when all of the combined streams emit at least once.